# I want to copy ActiveX control from one sheet to another. My method is not reliable. Can you think of something reliable?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code sometimes produces the error "Unable to use the paste method". Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't - even though I run the macro on the exact same files.

Can you figure out why or propose a more stable method?

```
Set x = srcWbk.Sheets("C").OLEObjects("MCFB")
Set y = x.Duplicate
xName = x.Name
y.Cut
trgtWbk.Sheets("C").Activate
trgtWbk.Sheets("C").Range("O1").Select
With trgtWbk.Sheets("C")
    .Paste
    .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count).Name = xName
    .Activate
End With
```

Comment: seems like you are copying between workbooks. Make sure the references are set to both and they are open. I am not even able to reproduce your problem and the method is def a reliable one. The problem lies somewhere else it's probably related to your workbooks references.

Answer (score 1):

*this is a temporary answer. it will be deleted when the OP sees the code*

copied the buttons about one hundred times with no errors. Make sure your `trgtWbk` is properly closed and references are free'd. I cant see the entire code and how you manipulate your workbook object so it's very hard to tell why you are getting the error.

try re-arranging your code to best suit the below schema

```
Sub Main()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Desktop\Book2.xlsm")

    CopyActiveX "cmd1", wb1, wb2

    CopyActiveX "cmd2", wb1, wb2

    wb2.Save
    wb2.Saved = True
    wb2.Close

    Set wb2 = Nothing
End Sub


Sub CopyActiveX(cName As String, ByRef srcWbk As Workbook, ByRef trgtWbk As Workbook)

    Dim x As OLEObject
    Dim y As OLEObject
    Dim xName As String

    Set x = srcWbk.Sheets("C").OLEObjects(cName)
    Set y = x.Duplicate
    xName = x.Name
    y.Cut
    trgtWbk.Sheets("C").Activate
    trgtWbk.Sheets("C").Range("O1").Select
    With trgtWbk.Sheets("C")
        .Paste
        .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count).Name = xName
        .Activate
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful asnwer. I switched to working with form buttons instead, and haven't had similar problems there.